# CSS font size and bootstrap modal size changes when deploying compared to local browser

Tags: css, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bootstrap-modal, plotly-dash

I have created a web app using plotly with CCS files in my assets folder. When running the app locally it all looks great. However, when uploading to AWS on Elastic Beanstalk my font sizes get quite a lot bigger. Most notably within bootstrap components (banner and modal). I have found several people asking this question, and I have tried their solutions (webpage zooming and media min-width) but it doesn't seem to work. Does anyone have any ideas? I would be very appreciative as the deployed app doesn't look very good at all!

Below is the relevant code (I think)

```
CSS

body {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-left: 1vw;
    padding-right: 1vw;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    padding-left: 0.9em;
}

h2 {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    padding-left: 0em;
    padding-bottom: 0.6em;
}

.username-login {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 1vw;
    padding-top: 3vh;
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: left;
    text-align: left;
}

.username-text {
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 0.5vw;
    display: inline-block;
    color: grey;
    line-height: 25px;
    /*justify-content: center;*/
}
```

Python code:

```
app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
    meta_tags=[
        {
            'charset': 'utf-8',
        },
        {
            'name': 'viewport',
            'content': 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1'
        }
    ]
)

#Info is the modal css but written as a python dictionary 

info_overall = {
    'zIndex': '100',
    'max-width': 'none',
    'overflow-y': 'auto',
    'max-height': '80vh',
    'position': 'relative',
    'margin': 'auto',
    'width': '80vw',
    'background': '#1e1e1e',
    'top': '18%',
}

info_body={
    'background':'grey',
    'display': 'grid',
    'grid-template-columns':'auto auto auto auto auto',
    'grid-template-rows': 'auto auto auto auto',
}
```

You can see that the modal is bigger on the deployed app (overlaps a button) as well as the name and logout text. Many thanks in advance! As you can probably tell I am very new to this!

Deployed APP:
[image: deployed_app]
Local APP:
[image: local_app]

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea here, this could be caused by having different versions of a library in your local and production environments eg. dash-bootstrap-components.
You can use your browser's developer tools to get the css and html code from both versions, and use diff to see if there is any difference, this could also help you narrow down the problem.